# How to select multiple fields in the same row? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I [asked a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111523/how-would-i-perform-math-within-a-sql-query-to-calculate-percent-difference) about using MySQL to tally results to a survey.

Now my question is, if I had a table of survey questions, a table of survey choices, and a table of users answers to those survey questions, how would I select the survey question along with all the choices for that survey within the same query?

Questions Table

```
question_id (int)
question (text)
```

Choices Table

```
choice_id (int)
question_id (int)
choice_text (varchar)
```

Answers Table

```
answer_id (int)
question_id (int)
choice_id (int)
```

What SELECT should I do to get the survey question along with all the choices for that survey (known or unknown amount) all in the same query? (if possible, also do the math, found in my other question,  within the same query)

I'm not so advanced with MySQL.

Thanks

**EDIT:** 
Sorry, What I meant was, I'm trying to get a SELECT statement to select the question, and all the choices corresponding to that question, in one row.

If I do something like

```
SELECT question_id, question, choice_id, choice_text FROM questions LEFT JOIN choices USING(question_id)
```

I get multiple rows, one for each choice_id.

The results should be something like

```
question     choice_1  choice_2  choice_3
A or B or C     A          B        C
```

The math part is tallying up the results to the survey, and yes, the choice_id is a PK, if that helps.

Comment: Do you just want the chocies, or also the counts? What is your "other question" and what "math" do you want doing?

Comment: You're not looking for any information regarding the correct answer? Just the question/choice possibilities?

Comment: @Evan: it's a survey, not a test - there is no correct answer.

Comment: Your database design might not be normalised. Is your choice_id a PK? If so, what would happen if the question_id in the answers table didn't match with the choice_id's question_id?

Comment: You can't do that. At least, you won't be able to fetch it with php ( you can actually do a UNION() but still won't be able to fetch it properly ). What you can do is select the question, all choices with proper answers and run them through a loop. Multiple questions too, ofc.

Comment: i initially thought that it couldn't be done, I just figured I'd ask. Thanks to all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the questions and the choices for each question:

```
SELECT question, choice_text
FROM questions
JOIN choices
ON questions.question_id = choices.question_id
```

Add LEFT before JOIN if you also want questions that have no choices.

To get the counts for each answer you could do this:

```
SELECT question, choice_text, COUNT(answers.choice_id)
FROM questions
JOIN choices
    ON questions.question_id = choices.question_id
LEFT JOIN answers
    ON questions.question_id = answers.question_id
    AND choices.choice_id = answers.choice_id
GROUP BY questions.question_id, choices.choice_id
ORDER BY questions.question_id, choices.choice_id
```

To get the number of people that selected each answer as a percentage (per question) use the following query:

```
SELECT question, choice_text, COUNT(answers.choice_id) * 100 / questiontotal
FROM questions
JOIN (
        SELECT questions.question_id, COUNT(answers.choice_id) AS questiontotal
        FROM questions
        LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.question_id = answers.question_id
        GROUP BY questions.question_id
    ) AS answercounts
    ON questions.question_id = answercounts.question_id
JOIN choices ON questions.question_id = choices.question_id
LEFT JOIN answers
    ON questions.question_id = answers.question_id
    AND choices.choice_id = answers.choice_id
GROUP BY questions.question_id, choices.choice_id
ORDER BY questions.question_id, choices.choice_id;
```

Here's the testdata I used:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (question_id int, question nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO questions (question_id, question) VALUES
(1, 'Foo?'),
(2, 'Bar?');

CREATE TABLE choices (choice_id int, question_id int, choice_text nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO choices (choice_id, question_id, choice_text) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Foo1'),
(2, 1, 'Foo2'),
(3, 1, 'Foo3'),
(4, 2, 'Bar1'),
(5, 2, 'Bar2');

CREATE TABLE answers (answer_id int, question_id int, choice_id int);
INSERT INTO answers (answer_id, question_id, choice_id) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 2, 4),
(4, 2, 5);
```

And the output I get with the last query on this data:

```
'Foo?', 'Foo1', 66.6667
'Foo?', 'Foo2', 0.0000
'Foo?', 'Foo3', 33.3333
'Bar?', 'Bar1', 50.0000
'Bar?', 'Bar2', 50.0000
```

In the update to your question you say you want to return all the values for one question on one row. I would recommend that you do *not* try to do this, and instead use the method I have given you above. If you need to present the data in one row to your end-user, this can be done using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest Mark Byers's answer, though theoretically if you need them "all in one row" just for viewing purposes but not as part of a PHP routine you can do.

```
SELECT question, GROUP_CONCAT(choice_text) as choice_texts
FROM questions
JOIN choices
ON questions.question_id = choices.question_id
GROUP BY question;
```

The output would be

```
'Foo?', 'Foo1,Foo2,Foo3'
'Bar?', 'Bar1,Bar2'
```

Note 'Foo1,Foo2,Foo3' would be returned as one column not three columns, and GROUP_CONCAT has a maximum of 1024 characters in its output by default though it can be increased. Its not recommended if the results might be large

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Answers table probably doesn't need the QuestionID column.

This will get you the question text, choice text, and the number of answers per choice.

```
SELECT Questions.question, Choices.choice_text, Count(Answers.*) AS N
FROM Questions INNER JOIN Choices ON Questions.question_id = Choices.question_id
     LEFT JOIN Answers ON Choices.choice_id = Answers.choice_id
GROUP BY Questions.question_id, Choices.choice_id
```

Edit: unless you're very, very good at SQL, it's probably best to forget about the "all one row" part - unless the number of choices per question is not only known, but constant, and even in that case, it ain't easy. It's really a display issue, so deal with it when you display the results.

Comment: And I wish I could give another +1 for pointing out the unnecessary QuestionID column.

Comment: Unfortunately your query doesn't seem to work for me though. I get 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS N
FROM Questions
INNER JOIN Choices ON Questions.question_id = Choices.q' at line 1

Comment: It might be a difference in syntax between MySQL and other SQL servers: try it without the word "INNER". (My experience, such as it is, is with MS SQL Server.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT questions.question_id, questions.question, choices.choice_id, choices.question_id
FROM questions, choices 
WHERE questions.question_id = choices.question_id 
AND questions.question_id = "Something"
```

Should work, I think.